# A way around Qt apps size

Tags: c++, qt, code-size

A Qt app with the networking library and the GUI library gets to about 10MB; that is, without code.

For people with Internet connection like mine, that is a bit inconvenient; specially when it comes to a program that is rarely used (i.e. used once and then left.)

I tried to use LZMA and LZMA2 compressions to compress the exe files, and it did nothing.

I would like to make the code itself smaller, is there a way to do that? How much can I go down in size? At least when it comes to the networking library.

PS: I wouldn't like to use UPX or such applications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try statically linking; this may be able to discard unused code from the library. Please note, however, that this may impact your obligations under Qt's open source licenses;  distributing a closed-source (generally, non-LGPL) application statically linked against a LGPL-licensed library brings with it [additional obligations](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/299303-the-ultimate-gpllgpl-discussion/page__view__findpost__p__2899002) when compared to the dynamic-linking case. Of course, if your application is GPL or LGPL licensed itself, this is no problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could rebuild Qt from source, skipping the bits that you don't need. See [configure options](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/configure-options.html) for a list of things that you can leave out. E.g. `-no-openssl` will make the network library smaller.

Comment: I built (very) stripped version of qt - qtcore and qtgui together were about 1.8 MB big. But i disabled almost everything and used hardcore compiler flags.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a guide I wrote to making Qt smaller:

http://www.formortals.com/build-qt-static-small-microsoft-intel-gcc-compiler/